# Sony Bravia App development

Tags: sony

I has just bought a Sony Bravia Internet TV. And as a developer (just web back end developer), I want to try to develop an app for my TV. But, I cannot find any tutorial or introduction about how to develop an app for Sony Bravia TV, excepts Sony Google TV and a Javascript SDK for Japanese. Unluckily, I don't know Japanese.

Is there any English Tutorial Sony Bravia TV Development?

Maybe you rate down for this dummy question. But, it is need for me. :)

Comment: This might be something better to ask in chat, unfortunately.

Comment: I asked in chat, @ChrisForrence. But no one cared. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can develop apps under the Opera TV Store as Tonni suggested. But your app won't be available on your TV homescreen like the other native apps (Media player, YouTube, etc).

If you develop the app under Opera TV store, then you'll have to open the Opera store app first and then find your app under the "My Apps" section. Using this method, you can create HTML5 based apps, where you have to host the HTML pages on an external server. There is no device SDK and you can't take advantage of the native functionalities.

If only there is a way to create native apps similar to YouTube and Skype have done already, then it will be better and we can take advantage of the native features like playing AVI or FLV files.

Comment: How can I open native app(Browser) without network connectivity?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a new Bravia TV it's most likely using Opera. So to get more info on app development please go to http://dev.opera.com/tv

Answer (score 1):

Based on the chart at https://developer.sony.com/develop/tvs/
only HTML5 apps were supported on the model you have.  My new TV and Blu-ray player appear to support Google Cast.

"The HTML5 development kit for Sony TVs and home entertainment systems is currently only available to selected partners, but if you have a great app idea, we encourage you to get in touch with us. Explain your idea and tell us about your company. We will sign an NDA with selected partners, and then provide more detailed specs about our platform to you. We will also provide integration support to ensure compatibility across all our HTML5 capable products. In addition, limited selected partners may be offered premium placement opportunities."